# READIN IMAP MAIL with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to read a IMAP mail and quite everything is going fine, but ... SOMETIMES, I cannot have the right FILENAME but something like this as filename:

...quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($mbox,$jk,$fpos))

--_>>>>

?iso-8859-1?Q?NOVO_MODELO_INTERGLOBO_BL_-_MINERAÇÃO_GUIDI_092-15_093?= =?iso-8859-1?Q?-15_X_STONE_INTERN....xls?

(Downloading the file and RENAMING it taking OUT the last ? the content is correct and the file opened.

Which kind of control have to set? Any idea?

Comment: Not sure what your question here is... If that is the name of the resource, then what is the issue? note that the name contains non-ascii characters which is why it has to be encoded inside an email message.

Comment: .... I am trying to work with ATTACHMENTS .... and I can not have the right name of the file. The content is correct...

Comment: You say: ....which is why it has to be encoded inside an email message ... OK But I am READING the mail and I should DECODE it, isnt'it? But I do NOT know how ....

Comment: Take a look at this page in the php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php

Comment: it seems to be fine ..... I made some modification but it is ok. I will try with other kind of att. to see if it's working with all of them. Thank you.